# How to debug a missing Gem's assets?

Tags: rubygems, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am adding the [autoNumeric](https://github.com/randoum/autonumeric-rails) gem to a project. On my local development environment, `assets:precompile` or `rails s` results in `Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'autonumeric' (in myapp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)`.

I have tried:

- removing/re-adding gems
- restarting server (when trying `rails s`)
- adding `bundle exec` to commands
- creating a new clean VM with same codebase

The puzzling thing for me, is that it is running fine an our CI server and another developer's machine. All gem versions are the same, codebase is the same.

The only environmental difference I can see is that the environments I'm failing on were setup using `ruby-build/rbenv` and the passing ones using `rvm`.

If I manually copy the assets from the Gem's source into my app, then it resolves the issue on my failing environments, but is not a viable solution.

What are some other steps I can take to help debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored the next apparent option, which was to rebuild a new development VM using `rvm` vs `ruby-build/rbenv`. This succeeded in overcoming the issue, so I could deduce that the issue lies in an improper method of using `rbenv` in my other environments.